# Flex Error: "Source could not be found for flash.events.NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS" when trying to use events

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 6 for developing my Flex projects. If I ctrl+click on any events (such as `NET_STATUS`) I'm shown the following error:

[image: Source could not be found for flash.events.NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS in source file]

I have imported the events library using `import flash.events.*`.

My live streaming also not working - is that related to this?

Comment: this means you cannot see the code of the NetStatusEvent class inside the playerglobal.swc which is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal because it is not a flex class and source for it is not provided with sdk. However, it can't be a reason  of your problems with streaming - you shall search for it elsewhere.